# regex for digits between dots

Tags: regex

Hi I am struggling with regex in Java for those scenarios:

```
  String testtt = "aha.comment.1.app"; // should pass
  String testtt2 = "aha.comment1.app"; // should fail
```

My **logical** proposition was:

```
 String regex = ".\\.[0-9]\\..+";
```

but it's not working...

I want to have a regex that will just check if in the whole string there is a digit/number wrapped with two dots e.g `.1.`, `.22.` and also the characters can stay before and after.

other test scenarios:

```
a.1.b.c.d.2.a // should pass
a.2.b.c2.a.1. // should not pass
```

any hints?

of course i am using `testtt.matches(regex)`

Comment: Why would `a.2.b.c2.a.1.` fail? It contains `.2.` so that's a pass based on your description, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the string can not start and end with a dot, one option is to use a positive lookahead to assert  dot-digits-dot

```
^(?=.+\.\d+\.)[^.\n\r]+(?:\.[^.\n\r]+)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/52GsKM/1)

In Java if you are using matches, and with the doubled backslashes

```
String regex = "(?=.+\\.\\d+\\.)[^.\\n\\r]+(?:\\.[^.\\n\\r]+)+";
```

If the dot can be anywhere, and there must be digits-dot-digits and either chars a-z or digits between the dots:

```
 ^(?!.*(?:[a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z]))(?!.*?\.\.)[a-z0-9.]*\.\d\.[a-z0-9.]*$
```

See another [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mMOgV/1)

Comment: it's great what if it can starts or ends with dot?

Comment: @Ernesto Why should this fail in that case? `a.2.b.c2.a.1.`

Comment: because 'c2' is not splited by dot

Comment: anyway you're must have been graduated from Regex University :P

Comment: @Ernesto This would allow the dots at the start and end  https://regex101.com/r/08Q9KZ/1

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate and admire your regex skills!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
^\.?(?:\d+|[a-z]+)(?:\.(?:\d+|[a-z]+))*\.?$
```

This assumes you are performing a verification of a period-separated string which can only have digits or letters between the periods, not both.

https://regex101.com/r/nCoIQu/1

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\.[0-9]*\..*
```

these regex may help you